# I am finding it difficult to create an .exe from python script using pyinstaller. My script executes perfectly but when i run the .exe i get traceback

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyinstaller, specifications

My Python script executes perfectly in a virtual environment which has python 3.9.2 but when i create an exe using pyinstaller the exe doesn.t work, i get tracebacks of certain modules missing but when i add the missing modules with the help of spec files it then gives a traceback of some other modules missing on and on.

```
File “modin\config\pubsub.py”, line 118, in get
File “modin\config\envvars.py”, line 32, in _get_raw_from_config
File “os.py”, line 669, in getitem
KeyError: ‘MODIN_ENGINE’

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File “file.py”, line 1
118, in
File “file.py”, line 8
38, in commonsteps
File “swifter\swifter.py”, line 358, in apply
File “swifter\swifter.py”, line 259, in _modin_apply
File “”, line 961, in _find_and_load
File “”, line 950, in find_and_load_unlocked
File “”, line 655, in load_unlocked
File “PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py”, line 476, in exec_module
File "modin\pandas_init.py", line 180, in
File “modin\config\pubsub.py”, line 107, in subscribe
File "modin\pandas_init.py", line 109, in _update_engine
File “modin\config\pubsub.py”, line 120, in get
File “modin\config\envvars.py”, line 75, in _get_default
File “”, line 961, in _find_and_load
File “”, line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File “”, line 655, in load_unlocked
File “PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py”, line 476, in exec_module
File "distributed_init.py", line 1, in
File “”, line 961, in _find_and_load
File “”, line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File “”, line 655, in _load_unlocked
File “PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py”, line 476, in exec_module
File “distributed\config.py”, line 17, in
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\01_xew\02_ret
```

after getting this traceback i tried to specify the modin engine in the script but then got this traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "swifter\swifter.py", line 340, in apply
  File "DTC_dask.py", line 840, in compare
  File "pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 65, in new_method
  File "pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 365, in wrapper
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DTC_dask.py", line 1127, in <module>
  File "DTC_dask.py", line 847, in commonsteps
  File "swifter\swifter.py", line 358, in apply
  File "swifter\swifter.py", line 259, in _modin_apply
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "modin\pandas\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
  File "modin\config\pubsub.py", line 107, in subscribe
  File "modin\pandas\__init__.py", line 122, in _update_engine
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "distributed\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "distributed\config.py", line 17, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\TTC01017\\Documents\\My Received Files\\exe_392_dask\\distributed\\distributed.yaml'
[16400] Failed to execute script 'DTC_dask' due to unhandled exception!
```

After this when i try to add the missing directory to the exe using spec file it further then gives a traceback of some other module missing

I guess the main issue here is pyinstaller not properly coping the dependent libraries to the exe.... can anyone help with this issue and how to create the pyinstaller with spec file which takes care of all the dependent libraries.

Comment: try ensuring you have the lastest version of pyinstaller. use `pip install --upgrade pyinstaller`

Answer (score 0):

In both cases a `FileNotFoundError` is thrown, double check that the file path is correct and if that is the case try using `/` instead of `\\`

```
'C:/Users/TTC01017/Documents/My Received Files/exe_392_dask/distributed/distributed.yaml'
```